# MIPS memcpy issue (i think)

Tags: c, mips, memcpy, memory-alignment

I have some software that I have working on a redhat system with icc and it is working fine. When I ported the code to an IRIX system running with MIPS then I get some calculations that come out as "nan" when there should definitely be values there.

I don't have any good debuggers on the non-redhat system, but I have tracked down that some of my arrays are getting "nan" sporadically in them and that is causing my dot product calculation to come back as "nan."

Seeing as how I can't track it down with a debugger, I am thinking that the problem may be with a memcpy. Are there any issues with the MIPS compiler memcpy() function with dynamically allocated arrays? I am basically using

```
 memcpy(to, from, n*sizeof(double));
```

And I can't really prove it, but I think this may be the issue. Is there some workaround? Perhaps sme data is misaligned? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be surprised if your problem came from a bug in `memcpy`. It may be an alignment issue: are your `double`s sufficiently aligned? (They will be if you only store them in `double` or `double[]` objects or through `double*` pointers but might not be if you move them around via `void*` pointers). X86 platforms are more tolerant to misalignment than most.

Did you try compiling your code with gcc at a high warning level? (Gcc is available just about everywhere that's not a microcontroller or mainframe. It may produce slower code but better diagnostics than the “native” compiler.)

Of course, it could always be a buffer overflow or other memory management problem in some unrelated part of the code that just happened not to cause any visible bug on your original platform.

If you can't get a access to a good debugger, try at least printf'ing stuff in key places.

Comment: I will check to see if gcc is on there. I doubt it is, as this is a pretty much purpose-built system. Didnt realize it might have more warnings than another.

They arrays are defined as double * 

If I used something like totalview on the original platform and turned on memory debugging, it should still give me an answer w.r.t. buffer overflows and such right? Maybe I will give that a try, even though its giving correct answers there

Comment: @Derek: Yes, trying something like totalview or valgrind (which is free and has a good reputation) is a good idea, and it might find bugs even on the original platform. It's not guaranteed to find the bug (if any), but it's usually worth the time trying.

Comment: That's my bet -- that the destination is not properly aligned, so while the memcpy works, accessing the data after is not expecting unaligned data.

Comment: Turns out after running this with totalview, i still couldnt find a memory out of bounds condition or anything. By dumb luck I put in a print statement in a couple of places and this was the issue - overflowing the space by 1. Must be luck that it worked on the intel system.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for the memory regions `to` and `from` to overlap? `memcpy` isn't required to handle overlapping memory regions. If this is your problem then the solution is as simple as using [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is `sizeof()` definitely supported?

Comment: Yes. It returns 8 on this system